# Why does the bash script not use imported text file data to run the entire code?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to whitelist the text file stored IP address list in Cloudflare WAF. I use the following Cloudflare API4 curl containing bash script for this.

This Cloudflare API script cannot use the imported IP address data. When I debug, it shows an "invalid IP address" message (from the Cloudflare end).

I want to load this script's IP address data from a separate text file.

How do I import data from a file?

My locally saved file includes data in the following format.

```
123.123.123.124 
123.123.123.57 
123.123.123.91
```

This is the Cloudflare IP whitelist script.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
input="/var/download/ip.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
done < "$input"
    
    for i in "${line[@]}"
    do
       : 
       # do whatever on $i
        echo $i
        curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules" \
             -H "X-Auth-Email: myemail" \
             -H "X-Auth-Key: globle API key" \
             -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
             --data '{"mode":"whitelist","configuration":{"target":"ip","value":"'$i'"},"notes":"Google Bot IP"}'

    done
```

Comment: How does it work if you omit the `IFS=` part, leaving that line with just `while read -r line` ?

Comment: 1. The file was generated on Windows system, so your IP addresses contain an unexpected carriage return character. You can confirm this with a little bit of debugging: add the command `printf "IP > %s </n" "$ip"` instead of your unadorned `echo $ip`. Look for a `<` at the **beginning** of the line

Comment: @sotto-voce I have removed the `IFS=` part, but I get the same error. @roaima no `ip.txt` file created on same Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Comment: 2. Your first loop reads each line from the file. Your second loop contains a single entry that corresponds to just the last value read

Comment: @roaima, Could you please tell me how I correct it?

Comment: Replace the `echo` with the `printf…` like I suggested, and then please add the literal results to your question. Copy and paste. It should help explain why the "IP address" is being reported by CloudFlare as invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way I would implement this script in **Bash** (per the original question).  Certain parts are different from your example, and I'll explain why I'm suggesting them.

```
#!/bin/bash

# the IP addresses are in a file, one per line
ip_file='/var/download/ip.txt'

# get the IP addresses from the file into an array
while read -r ip_line
do
  ip_list[${#ip_list[@]}]="${ip_line}"
done < "${ip_file}"

# was the file empty?
[[ ${#ip_list[@]} -lt 1 ]] && {
  echo "$0: Error, no ip addresses in ${ip_file}" >&2
  exit 1
}

# parameterize the unchanging parts of the curl commands
url='https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules'
my_email='my-email@my-domain'
api_key='1234567890abcdef'

# loop through the list of IPs
for ip_addr in "${ip_list[@]}"
do
  # use a here document to put the IP into the json blob
  # (the here document is not indented)
  whitelist_json=$(cat - <<EOJSON
{
  "mode":"whitelist",
  "configuration": {
    "target": "ip",
    "value": "${ip_addr}"
  },
  "notes":"Google Bot IP"
}
EOJSON
)

  # tell my user what I'm doing
  echo "Submitting whitelist for IP ${ip_addr}"

  # the curl command to submit the address
  echo curl \
  -X POST "${url}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "X-Auth-Email: ${my_email}" \
  -H "X-Auth-Key: ${api_key}" \
  --data "${whitelist_json}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` in front of `curl` after you've run it against your `ip.txt` file and verified it generates the correct command arguments.

If your `ip.txt` file has Unix/Linux line endings, then you can replace the four lines of the `while read ...` loop with one line:

```
readarray -t ip_list < "${ip_file}"
```

The `readarray` approach is just one line and fairly self-explanatory.  On the other hand, the `while read ...` loop gives you a chance to alter the `${ip_line}` value before it's saved into the array.  Perhaps to strip out leading/trailing whitespace characters, or test the line is empty, etc.

The statement that saves the value into the array is my method of implementing a `push(array, value)` action in Bash, which doesn't have push().  Essentially, it gets the current length of the array, and uses that number as the index of the next element to save the new value.

The URL, e-mail address, and API key are put into variables to keep the length of the `curl` arguments short and easy to understand, but that's my own personal preference.

For the JSON blob (data structure), I have found that it's far easier to assemble it with a shell `Here Document`.  Single-quote and Double-quote characters aren't stripped from the string, and you can use multiple lines with indentation to make the JSON readable by people who may need to alter it.  The surrounding construct to use the here document - `$(cat - <<EOJSON` and `JSON )` - can puzzle people, but a comment line can help that.  IMO it's worthwhile when it makes the JSON easier to understand by the next coder working with the script.  Or you can keep the JSON all on one long line.  There here document still will reduce the games you need to play with single-quote and double-quote characters.

I use here documents for other complex strings that want to have quotes around some elements that are built from shell variables.  JMESPath querys for `jq` and MySQL commands are ones that come to mind.

I tend to not indent here documents in my scripts.  Indenting the ending line (`EOJSON` in this case) requires tabs in most shells, which are prone to being rewritten into spaces that will break the here document.  Indenting the JSON lines but not the ending line can be more confusing than when none of the lines are indented, with a comment to explain it.  This, too, is just my personal opinion.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tested your script, but the Cloudflare CURL part not working (if it runs, IP does not pass to Cloudflare WAF).  Furthermore, it is not showing the correct command arguments. Then I replaced your modified Cloudflare curl part with the original, the script started working.

Comment: @Chathu I'm glad you got it working!